# How to reset the question number for different sections in exam class without getting multiply defined labels

Tags: warnings, exam

This is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}
\begin{document}

\section{ONE}
\begin{questions}  
\question First question
\question Second questoion
\end{questions}

\section{TWO}
\begin{questions}  
\question First question
\question Second questoion
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

The problem I have with this is that there is a warning for multiply defined labels.
Which in a very big document sometimes makes the compilation hang.

Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Looks to me that the question counter *is* reset at new sections?! The problem seems to be that the value of the question counter is used for some internal references of the type `question@\arabic{question}` which causes multiple labels *because* the counter is reset...

Comment: I guess I didn't phrase the question properly.

But, yes, the counter is reset, but I get the mulptiply defined label warning because the counter is reset each time.

And this is a real problem as the document gets bigger because of all the mulptiply defined labels warning and the compiler hangs.

Comment: Then why is your question »How to reset the question number for different sections«?

Comment: sorry I was just trying to keep the question short, they do reset but not without errors/warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this but I found a way to fix this recently, any other ideas and comments on what I did are very welcome.

I changed two lines in the `exam.cls` which are

line2566

```
\edef\@queslabel{question@\arabic{question}}%
```

to

```
\edef\@queslabel{question@\arabic{section}@\arabic{subsection}@\arabic{question}}%
```

and

line2893

```
\edef\@partlabel{part@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}%
```

to

```
\edef\@partlabel{part@\arabic{section}@\arabic{subsection}@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}%
```

I only changed this two since they were the ones giving me the warnings and I don't use `subparts` or `subsubparts`. I guess if needed, those should be changed too.