# Reset question numbering in exam class without affecting grade table

Tags: counters, exam, gradetable

**Purpose:** I need to create a document that contains multiple individual exams. I have already applied heavy customisations to the exam class so I wish to continue using it rather than having to start all over again!

**Problem:** For each individual exam, I need the question number to restart at one and for individual grade point tables to be produced. If I use two separate question environments, then there will be label errors and the grade tables will BOTH show the grades for the questions in section section. If I use one question environment, then the questions numbering will not reset to zero at each section. I cannot use a fake counter because my customisations heavily depend on `\thequestion`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\partialpointtable{1}[h][questions]
\partialpointtable{2}[h][questions]

\fullwidth{\section{ONE}}
\fullwidth{\subsection{one}}
\partialpointtable{1}[h][questions]

\begin{questions}
\begingradingrange{1}
\question[10] This is the first question
\question[20] This the second question
\begin{parts}
    \part[10] This is a part worth 10 marks
\end{parts}
\endgradingrange{1}
%\end{questions} %--- If you uncomment this, errors will start happening...

\fullwidth{\section{TWO}}
\fullwidth{\subsection{one}}
\partialpointtable{2}[h][questions]
%\begin{questions} %--- If you uncomment this, errors will start happening...
\begingradingrange{2}
\question[3] This is the first question
\question[4] This the second question
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] This is a part worth 1 mark
\end{parts}
\endgradingrange{2}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

**Attempted solutions**

1. Fix the label problems using:
   [How to reset the question number for different sections in exam class without getting multiply defined labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195484/how-to-reset-the-question-number-for-different-sections-in-exam-class-without-ge). This didn't work for me as the grade tables began throwing errors...
2. Using `\setcounter{question}{0}` after `\section` did restart the numbering but gave `LaTeX Warning: Label multiply defined.` warnings everywhere. Both the grade tables also showed the marks for the questions in Section 2 only.

Any help would be very appreciated!! I'm open to all suggestions including changing the exam.cls file, combining separate exam files, etc etc.

Comment: try [this trick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209533/71471)

Comment: huh, that's actually quite a neat trick! I would rather not have to move everything down a level (e.g parts become subparts) but if there are no other suggestions then I will just restructure everything. Thanks again!

Comment: This is brilliant  \setcounter{question} {0} it works perfectly for me!

Comment: @jon As long as you don't need to do cross-references amongst the questions. (LaTeX complains about multiply defined labels)